# Maven package error when trying to build a simple Spark stand alone Java app

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I was trying to build a simple Spark stand alone Java application exactly as in [Spark - Self-Contained Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications).

```
/* SimpleApp.java */
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class SimpleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<String> logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache();

        long numAs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("a")).count();
        long numBs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("b")).count();

        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

The package structure is as below

```
./pom.xml
./src
./src/main
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/SimpleApp.java
```

And here is the pom.xml

```
<project>
    <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Simple Project</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I run `mvn package`, I get the following errors.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/fengyich/Dev/Sandbox/SimpleApp/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[8,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Dataset
  location: class SimpleApp
[ERROR] /Users/fengyich/Dev/Sandbox/SimpleApp/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[8,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable read
  location: variable spark of type org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

Comment: You compile SparkSql, but not the rest of Spark?

Comment: And try to use an IDE, don't just copy the example and assume they're correct

Comment: Ok. The issues has been resolved. There are at least two things that should be fixed in the java code. The first is need to import Dataset packages, org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset, and the other is the example used scala API when calling spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache(), in Java, it should be spark.read().textFile(logFile).cache(). Checked the API doc to get it work.

Answer (score 2):

Add one additional import line

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
```

Change

```
spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache();
```

to

```
spark.read().textFile(logFile).cache();
```

My pom.xml looks like below

```
<project>
  <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

That should resolve your issues

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to :
  `import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`

Answer (score -1):

you can try to add below plugin :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```